# clearRect not working when iterated?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

Why doesn't clearRect appear to work in this example?  I would expect only the last red rectangle to appear.  Instead, all ten are painted.

```js
var $c = document.getElementById("c");
var ctx = $c.getContext('2d');
var w = 400;
var h = 400;
$c.style.width = w + 'px';
$c.style.height = h + 'px';
$c.width = w;
$c.height = h;
for (var i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 400, 400);
  ctx.fillStyle = "red";
  ctx.rect(i * 10, i * 10, 10, 10);
  ctx.fill();
}
```

```html
<canvas id="c"></canvas>
```

Comment: It stacks up the different drawings and draws them all in one go, discarding the clearRect. You have to start a new path on every iteration -> http://jsfiddle.net/ms3yaok2/ You could also force a redraw by resetting the canvas -> http://jsfiddle.net/ms3yaok2/1/

Answer (score 0):

You need to separate the paths on which the rectangles are drawn so they can be cleared independently. You do this using `ctx.beginPath` and `ctx.closePath`.

```js
var $c = document.getElementById("c");
var ctx = $c.getContext('2d');
var w = 400;
var h = 400;
$c.style.width = w + 'px';
$c.style.height = h + 'px';
$c.width = w;
$c.height = h;

ctx.fillStyle = "red";

(function drawRect(i) {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 400, 400);

  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.rect(i * 10, i * 10, 10, 10);
  ctx.closePath();

  ctx.fill();

  if(i < 10)
      setTimeout(function() { drawRect(i + 1); }, 50);
})(0);
```

```html
<canvas id="c"></canvas>
```

Note: for fun, and so you can actually see the canvas being cleared, I've modified your code from a loop to a callback based animation.